# Install OpenCV to use with PyPy

Tags: python, opencv, pypy

I am trying to run OpenCV with PyPy, I tried everything to make it work, but so far I couldn't. Tried downloading opencv-python from its github repository (https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python) and then running setup.py myself, but it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  File "C:\pypy2.7-v7.1.1-win32\site-packages\skbuild\setuptools_wrap.py", line 578, in setup
    cmkr.make(make_args, env=env)
  File "C:\pypy2.7-v7.1.1-win32\site-packages\skbuild\cmaker.py", line 481, in make
    os.path.abspath(CMAKE_BUILD_DIR())))

An error occurred while building with CMake.
  Command:
    "cmake" "--build" "." "--target" "install" "--config" "Release" "--"
  Source directory:
    I:\Dropbox\project\opencv-python
  Working directory:
    I:\Dropbox\project\opencv-python\_skbuild\win32-2.7\cmake-build
Please see CMake's output for more information.
```

Tried running the command separately, but also gives me another error:
Error: could not load the cache.
- Also tried some solutions for that cache error but nothing.

I couldn't understand what was the issue, and also couldn't find any CMake output file. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: did you check the official documentation described [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d5/de5/tutorial_py_setup_in_windows.html)?

Comment: Something seems to be wrong with your cmake. Try uninstalling cmake and install it again using : `pip install cmake`. Then install opencv again.

Comment: @MohitMotwani Tried that before, got this error: "Problem with the CMake installation, aborting build. CMake executable is %s" % cmake_executable)

    Problem with the CMake installation, aborting build. CMake executable is cmake.                                                                                                     ERROR: Command "'c:\pypy2.7-v7.1.1-win32\pypy.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'c:\\users\\jota\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install-hlrp3d\\cmake\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) <- part command cant post it all.

Answer (score 0):

When I try the following on linux, I get nice cmake output. Perhaps you do not have cmake installed and on your path?

```
virtualenv -p /path/to/pypy2/bin/pypy /tmp/pypy2
source /tmp/pypy2/bin/activate
sudo apt install libtiff-dev libqt4-dev
python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

Comment: No, sorry, that is wrong. There is a problem even on linux

Answer (score -3):

I have no idea with installing by pypy, but I can give you some tips to install

1- install with pip:

- a- make sure yourself that python directory has write permission
- b- open cmd in administrative permission
- c- run the command `pip install opencv-contrib-python`

2- install through whl files, search for python binary files and
   install it locally(while installation you should have internet
   connection)